# Browser hangs while parsing georaster in geoblaze

Tags: javascript, performance, react, histogram, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I've been trying to create a histogram using geoblaze with a COG from s3.

The georaster is as follows: (generated with geoblaze.parse(url))

```js
{
  _data: '==hidden==',
  projection: 32618,
  height: 10768,
  width: 8101,
  pixelHeight: 0.05999999865889549,
  pixelWidth: 0.05999999865889549,
  xmin: 683581.3450000007,
  xmax: 684067.4049891364,
  ymax: 4944568.050001832,
  ymin: 4943921.970016273,
  noDataValue: -9999,
  numberOfRasters: 1,
  _geotiff: Te {
    source: ie {
      retrievalFunction: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
      blockSize: 65536,
      blockRequests: Map(0) {},
      blocks: [Map],
      blockIdsAwaitingRequest: null
    },
    littleEndian: true,
    bigTiff: false,
    firstIFDOffset: 186648956,
    cache: false,
    ifdRequests: [],
    ghostValues: null
  },
  getValues: [Function (anonymous)],
  toCanvas: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

The browser just keeps downloading resources and after some time it just pauses execution, as shown below:
[image]

The code is simply:

```
      const options: GeoblazeHistogramOptions = {
        scaleType: "ratio",
        numClasses: 10,
        classType: "equal-interval",
      };

      const histogram = (await geoblaze.histogram(
        signedObject.url,
        undefined,
        options
      )) as GeoblazeHistogram;
```

signedObject.url is `string` and is the link used to generate the the above georaster.

On running it locally on a nodejs instance using georaster, I try getting the georaster values and creating a custom histogram array as:

```js
import parseGeoraster from 'georaster'

const link = "==hidden=="

// ==== histogram to create bins from the array
// CHAT GPT + custom modifications
function createBinsForHist(values, min, max, numClasses, nodatavalue) {
    // Calculate the interval size
    const intervalSize = (max - min) / numClasses;
  
    // Initialize an array to store the bins and their frequencies
    const bins = [];
  
    // Initialize the bins
    for (let i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
      const binMin = min + i * intervalSize;
      const binMax = min + (i + 1) * intervalSize;
      const binLabel = `${binMin.toFixed(2)} - ${binMax.toFixed(2)}`;
      bins.push({ bin: binLabel, frequency: 0 });
    }
  
    // Iterate over the values and update the frequencies
    for (const w of values) {
      for (const row of w) {
        for (const value of row) {

          // the actual values

          if (value === nodatavalue) continue;
          
          let binIndex = Math.floor((value - min) / intervalSize);
          if (binIndex >= numClasses) {
            console.log('trouble figuring out bin for ' + value)
            console.log('got binIndex ' + binIndex)
            console.log('decrementing it to ' + numClasses - 1)
            binIndex = numClasses - 1
          }
            bins[binIndex].frequency++;
        }
      }
    }
  
    return bins;
  }

// log the start time
const startTime = new Date()
console.log('started at: ' + startTime.getHours() + ":" + startTime.getMinutes() + ":" + startTime.getSeconds())

parseGeoraster(link)
    .then(georaster => {
        // options directly copied from geoblaze.histogram function
        const options = { height: georaster.height, left: 0, right: georaster.width, bottom: georaster.height, top: 0, width: georaster.width };
        georaster.getValues(options)
            .then(values => {
                                // copied the min, max etc from the frontend
                const bins = createBinsForHist(values, 115, 206, 20, -9999)
                console.log(bins)

                // log the end time
                const endTime = new Date()
                console.log('ended at: ' + endTime.getHours() + ":" + endTime.getMinutes() + ":" + endTime.getSeconds())

                console.log('after: ' + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000) + 's')
                console.log('after: ' + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000 / 60) + 'min')
            })
    })
```

This gives the following output:

```
started at: 5:9:1
[
  { bin: '115.00 - 119.55', frequency: 5738259 },
  { bin: '119.55 - 124.10', frequency: 3260862 },
  { bin: '124.10 - 128.65', frequency: 3155341 },
  { bin: '128.65 - 133.20', frequency: 2471788 },
  { bin: '133.20 - 137.75', frequency: 2991296 },
  { bin: '137.75 - 142.30', frequency: 2634179 },
  { bin: '142.30 - 146.85', frequency: 2855303 },
  { bin: '146.85 - 151.40', frequency: 3018583 },
  { bin: '151.40 - 155.95', frequency: 1776806 },
  { bin: '155.95 - 160.50', frequency: 969735 },
  { bin: '160.50 - 165.05', frequency: 1203353 },
  { bin: '165.05 - 169.60', frequency: 1433433 },
  { bin: '169.60 - 174.15', frequency: 1727064 },
  { bin: '174.15 - 178.70', frequency: 2260746 },
  { bin: '178.70 - 183.25', frequency: 2568195 },
  { bin: '183.25 - 187.80', frequency: 2841456 },
  { bin: '187.80 - 192.35', frequency: 2353156 },
  { bin: '192.35 - 196.90', frequency: 2188344 },
  { bin: '196.90 - 201.45', frequency: 1048425 },
  { bin: '201.45 - 206.00', frequency: 159267 }
]
ended at: 5:10:40
after: 99.35s
after: 1.6558333333333333min
```

which is what was needed.

Though I managed to create this custom implementation for our particular use case, I need to understand why geoblaze is unable to do it to make it work for other generalized cases in the project. So what can be the issue here and are there any alternative ways to achieve it without breaking the app?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where attempting to gather any geoblaze stats for a GeoTIFF would hang indefinitely. The solution for me was to provide an input GeoJSON geometry as the second parameter. I just provide one the full extent of the GeoTIFF if I wanted stats on the full image.